# how to check if there is a null value inside LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

`CarrierDetailViewModel.SiteOptionModel`, this sometimes has a null value, then it throws the error like the below. Is there any way to check if there is no `truck.SiteId` then make it null otherwise assign value. How can I stop throwing the error but make it null when `truck.SiteId` is null.

```
from truck in database.Truck
   where truck.CarrierId == carrierId
         && (truck.IsDeleted == null || truck.IsDeleted == false)
   orderby truck.Code
   select new CarrierDetailViewModel.TruckModel2
   {
       Id = truck.TruckId,

       Site = new CarrierDetailViewModel.SiteOptionModel{
            Id = (int)truck.SiteId,
            Name = truck.Site.Name,
            Code = truck.Site.Code
       }
   } ;
```

**Error**

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Nullable object must have a value

Comment: When you say "make it null" what is "it"? What is the type of `SiteId`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a method, e.g. `CreateTruckModel2`

```
from truck in database.Truck
where truck.CarrierId == carrierId
     && (truck.IsDeleted == null || truck.IsDeleted == false)
orderby truck.Code
select CreateTruckModel2(truck);
```

and

```cs
public TruckModel2 CreateTruckModel2(Truck truck)
{
    if(truck?.SiteId == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    return new CarrierDetailViewModel.TruckModel2
    {
        Id = truck.TruckId,

        Site = new CarrierDetailViewModel.SiteOptionModel{
            Id = (int)truck.SiteId,
            Name = truck.Site.Name,
            Code = truck.Site.Code
        }
    };
}
```

Or just skip those with a where condition?

```cs
from truck in database.Truck
   where truck.CarrierId == carrierId
         && (truck.IsDeleted == null || truck.IsDeleted == false)
         && truck.SiteId != null
   orderby truck.Code
   select new CarrierDetailViewModel.TruckModel2
   {
       Id = truck.TruckId,

       Site = new CarrierDetailViewModel.SiteOptionModel{
            Id = (int)truck.SiteId,
            Name = truck.Site.Name,
            Code = truck.Site.Code
       }
   } ;
```